# Why is there a 8 pixel border to my CSS?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have an 8 pixel border that I'd like to increase, but I can't find where it's coming from. Also, if I use margin, it disproportionally adds to the border.

[image: 8 extra pixels? Why?]

The CSS and the entire project is available here: 
[CSS Resume Project](http://github.com/trtmn/resume)

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    src: url(Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}
.global {
    /*border: solid 10px lightgray;*/
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    align-self: center;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
}

p {
    font-weight: 300;
}

body {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Any help or even a pull request would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code in your question as well so people can learn from it in the future.

Comment: By default, there is an `8px` margin on the `body` element... remove that `body { margin: 0; }`. I would suggest using a [CSS Reset](http://cssreset.com/) to remove default/user-agent CSS like this.

Comment: See the `body` selector in this [**W3C default style sheet**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because it has a `margin` set by default and the `user-agent-stylesheet` looks something similar to this:

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px
}
```

so , simply reset `margin` in `body`

```css
body {
  margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**body** element has **8px** margin set as default by browsers.

You just need to change the margin of the **body** tag

```
body { 
    margin:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset/normalize your code by adding this code !

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
```